# How can you serialize/deserialize AWS Java SDK V2 classes into/from JSON?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, jackson, jackson-databind

With the AWS Java SDK V1, all of the classes were normal POJOs with standard getters and setters, so using Jackson you could just serialize/deserialize them easily.

Example:

```
TaskDefinition taskDefinition = ecsClient.describeTaskDefinition(new DescribeTaskDefinitionRequest().withTaskDefinition("myTaskDefinition")).getTaskDefinition();
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(taskDefinition));
```

Result:

```
{"taskDefinitionArn":"...","containerDefinitions":[...]}
```

---

But when I try this same thing with the AWS Java SDK V2, it results in an empty JSON object.

Example:

```
TaskDefinition taskDefinition = ecsClient.describeTaskDefinition(DescribeTaskDefinitionRequest.builder().taskDefinition("myTaskDefinition").build()).taskDefinition();
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(taskDefinition));
```

Result:

```
{}
```

And when I try to deserialize using Jackson, it results in an error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `software.amazon.awssdk.services.ecs.model.TaskDefinition` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is given here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2254

To serialize:

```
String taskDefinitionJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
        taskDefinition.toBuilder());
```

To deserialize:

```
TaskDefinition taskDefinition = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
        taskDefinitionJson,
        TaskDefinition.serializableBuilderClass())
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking everywhere for this, and this finally works.

Answer (score 0):

in the [docs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ecs/model/TaskDefinition.html), there is a method called serializableBuilderClass()

Try using that. I'd imagine the code would be something like:

```
TaskDefinition.serializableBuilderClass().build()
```